# Extracting Formula field in Data Loader Command Line Interface (CLI)

Tags: data-loader, formula-field, commandline

Need help. Can formula field be used in Command Line Interface ?
I have a requirment to automate the extraction process.And i have created few formula fields as per the requirment.but i keep getting the exception mentioned below

Exception occured during loading
com.salesforce.dataloader.exception.MappingInitializationException: Field mapping is invalid: AppId => Exception occured during loadingcom.salesforce.dataloader.exception.MappingInitializationException: Field mapping is invalid: AppId=>

```
        <map>
             <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="User"/>
             <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select AppId__c,AccountID__c,MappingID__c,
                   FirstName,LastName,Email,CreatedOn__c,CreatedDate,LastLoginDate,
                   ExternalAccount__c,Status__c,Description__c from User"/>
             <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
         </map>
```

I tried to find out the solution on net, but couldn't get.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You say you want to do extraction but you are engaged in field mapping (which is only done for DML) - are you sure you have specified doing an extract?

Comment: I have mentioned Process-Operation as EXTRACT                                 <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select AppId__c,AccountID__c,MappingID__c,FirstName,LastName,Email,CreatedOn__c,CreatedDate,LastLoginDate,ExternalAccount__c,Status__c,Description__c from User"/>
                                <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
                                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to load data directly into the formula field? You can't do that. Instead, load data into the other fields and the platform will calculate the formula field values for you.

Comment: I am not trying to load, I have created few formula fields.I am trying to extract the fields via CLIq but getting the above mentioned exception.                                   Please find the part of the Code.  <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select AppId__c,AccountID__c,MappingID__c,FirstName,LastName,Email,CreatedOn__c,CreatedDate,LastLoginDate,ExternalAccount__c,Status__c,Description__c from User"/>
                                <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
                                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>

Comment: So the error suggests a problem with field appId__c. Does the user running the CLI job have visibility into that field?

Comment: Thanks Corp1645. I had not set visiblity.